# How to receive on a list of possible values in erlang or elixir

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp

Is it possible to have a dynamic list of values that can be used in a guard for an erlang receive block.

e.g. I want to write something like

```
receive
  {Ref, Message} when Ref in [Refs]  ->
    %% Do stuff
```

Comment: If you provide a more detailed example about how you want to use it, maybe we can give you a more tailored idea.

Answer (score 1):

In Erlang, the guards are limited to the ones seen in [here](https://erlang.org/doc/reference_manual/expressions.html#guard-expressions) (no lists:member/2)
Given that the match is run for every message in the mailbox, I'd say that it makes sense to allow only simple checks there.

I see two options here:

1. Add unwanted messages to a [queue](http://erlang.org/doc/man/queue.html) in the state, and check that queue before the receive when required (when there's a receive with different clauses).
2. Include some tag in the messages to receive only those with a matching tag:

```erlang
receive {Ref, Tag, Message} when Tag == State#st.listen_tag -> ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
receive 
  {Ref, Message} when is_reference(Ref) ->
    handle_message( lists:member(Ref, Refs), Message );
  ...
```

`handle_message/2` can be implemented as

```
handle_message(true, Message) ->
  %% do stuff
  ;

handle_message(false, Message) ->
  ignore.
```